# How to print PDF file

Tags: android, pdf, flutter

I'm using [PdfViewer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview).
I want to print the PDF in flutter Android.

I want to intent to print PDF like:
[image: i want to intent to print pdf like]

Comment: You can Try this document may this will help you 
https://pub.dev/packages/printing

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution

```
var data = await getThePdfData(); // obtain the Uint8List
Printing.sharePdf(bytes: data);
```